# await in only valid in async function mongoldb

Tags: mongodb

```
app.get('/prenotazione', async (req, res) => {
      await dbo.collection("Noleggi").find({}).toArray().then((nol) => {
        await dbo.collection("Ogetti").findOne({ _id : nol.id_oggetto}).toArray().then((nol) => {
          console.log(nol);
          res.render('prenotazione', { ciao : nol});
        }).catch((error) => {
          res.status(500).write(error);
        });
      }).catch((error) => {
        res.status(500).write(error);
      });
    });
```

With one request the function work, but with the second request nested it doesn't,'t work and print me "Await in only valid in async function"

Answer (score 0):

It`s not necessary in the second await. But if u want it, u can add async:

```
await dbo.collection("Noleggi").find({}).toArray().then(async (nol) => {
  await dbo.collection("Ogetti").findOne({ _id : nol.id_oggetto}).toArray().then((nol) => {
    console.log(nol);
    res.render('prenotazione', { ciao : nol});
  }).catch((error) => {
    res.status(500).write(error);
  });
})
```